# Connect DOS and Windows 7 Computer with a crossover cable

Tags: windows-7, networking, ms-dos, crossover-cable

Ok, here is the scenario.... I have a DOS machine and a Windows 7 computer that I want to be able to share files together.

The Windows 7 computer will need to also be able to access the internet so I have installed a 2<sup>nd</sup> network card just to be used to connect it to the DOS machine. They are already connected via a crossover cable.

What steps do I need to take now to get these 2 computers talking, and will there be any complications in using 2 network cards on the Windows 7 computer?

I have put the Windows 7 computer and the DOS machine on the same Workgroup, and given them similar IPs, same subnet and same DNS. My Windows 7 machine can tell it is connected to the DOS machine, but it won't list it in Network Directory.

*After checking, this Dos machine already has MSClient 3.0 loaded on it. Is there anything else i can try?*

Comment: How did you put a DOS machine on a workgroup?! "Workgroup" sounds like a Windows concept. Ah Ms Network Client. Hope that does more than just help installing the OS.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything correctly, however you will not be able to see the DOS machine as an object on the network.  Since it does not have Windows and its subsequent applications, its just a machine with an IP address.  In order to get them talking, you need SMB on DOS, which MS has [here](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/Clients/MSCLIENT/).  I havent used this, so I dont know if/how well it works.  But, I dont see why it wouldnt.

Comment: the link worked when i posted it... strange.  Check out this site for alternatives.  http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/samba/dos.html